# SQL Server asks for 100GB for a dump with 1GB

Tags: sql-server-2008, backup, restore

Is it acceptable that SQL Server asks for 100GB free disk space to restore a 1GB dump file?

If no, what should be parameterized?

Comment: I am just curious if a tool like Litespeed was used to take that backup. We use Litespeed and our 300 GB database at 4 compression gives us a 35 gig backup file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is conceivable. You probably need to shrink the source database files before making the backup. Run sp_helpfile on the source database to see the files and sizes; when you restore from a backup, it will create those files at exactly the same size, though you can [move](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190447.aspx) them to different drives/directories.

If the log file or any of the data files are unnecessarily large, you can [shrink](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189035.aspx) them, do a new backup, and the restore will use less space. Just beware of performance implications if you get in a continual shrink/grow/shrink process.